# Elastic search master nodes not communicationg to one another

Tags: elasticsearch

We are planing to setup a cluster with 9 nodes where 3 are master nodes, 4 data nodes and 2 http nodes. Currently we have configured the master nodes and verify if the 3 master nodes are able to communicate with each other. We have installed elasticsearch version 7.5 on the 3 master nodes and the service is running successfully. However, we are unable to get the node information when running the curl URL at `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'`. When running the curl URL one each of the master node, rather than displaying all 3 master nodes info, it only shows the respective node information.  Following is the `elasticsearch.yml` configuration

```
   network.publish_host: _global:ipv4_
   network.bind_host: "0.0.0.0"
   discovery.seed_hosts: ["ip_of_masternode1", "ip_of_masternode2", "ip_of_masternode3"]
   discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
   node.master: true
   node.data: true
   action.destructive_requires_name: true
   indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 10%
```

How de we make all the 3 nodes communicate with each other. Currently ufw firewall is installed on 3 master nodes and all the 3 master nodes IPs are whitelisted in the firewall of each of the master node

Comment: can you provide your complete `elasticsearch.yml` of all master nodes?

Comment: ```cluster.name: es_cluster_20191227 ,node.name: ${HOSTNAME},bootstrap.memory_lock: true,network.publish_host: _global:ipv4_,
network.bind_host: "0.0.0.0",discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["ex51ssd78", "ex51ssd79", "ex51ssd80"],
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2,node.master: true,
node.data: false
```

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is incorrect. please set network.bind_host to  server IP.

Comment: I changed the network.bind_host to server IP, but now running the curl url at ```curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'``` is giving error ```curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused```

Comment: `network.bind_host: "0.0.0.0"` might be more permissive than you want, but is generally generally fine. Once you have `discovery.seed_hosts` you don't need `minimum_master_nodes` any more — remove that one. And if they don't form a cluster, we need logs. Logging for cluster forming improved a lot in 7.x, so please add the output from one node to the original question.